# Array of strings is not saved to Realm object using ObjectMapper

Tags: ios, swift, realm, objectmapper

This is how I declared `imageurls` inside My `Object`:

```
var imageURLs = List<String>()
```

and parsing:

```
func mapping(map: Map) {
    imageURLs <- map["image_urls"]
}
```

and this is what I am trying to parse:

```
{ "image_urls": ["a"] }
```

At the end above property is empty. Why?

Using Realm 3.3 so array of primitives should work.

Comment: tried **var imageURLs = [String]()**

Comment: `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Property 'imageURLs' is declared as 'NSArray', which is not a supported RLMObject property type. All properties must be primitives, NSString, NSDate, NSData, NSNumber, RLMArray, RLMLinkingObjects, or subclasses of RLMObject.`

Comment: You should try this `let imageURLs = List<String>()`
See this https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#property-attributes

Comment: then declare it as RLMArray

Comment: `Left side of mutating operator isn't mutable: 'imageURLs' is a 'let' constant`

Comment: @Sh_Khan `RLMArray`?

Answer (score 1):

In case you are working with both Realm an ObjectMapper, there is a pretty cool option for you, by using [ObjectMapper+Realm](https://github.com/jakenberg/ObjectMapper-Realm), you would be able to map arrays directly to realm lists, as follows:

```
func mapping(map: Map) {
    imageURLs <- (map["image_urls"], ListTransform<String>())
}
```

Note that by default the object mapper is unable to map arrays as realm lists, which is possible by using the above library.

Comment: You cannot do this, As ListTransform is expecting a RealmSwift Object, not a primitive type. Error : 'ListTransform' requires that 'String' inherit from 'Object'.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a variable in the function and map items to an array:

```
func mapping(map: Map) {
   var pathes = [String]()
   pathes <- map["image_urls"]
   self.imageUrls.add(pathes)
}
```

Or you could use the extension, which called `ObjectMapper+Realm`, as written above.

Answer (score 0):

You can map array of String using ObjectMapper like below, this works fine:

```
import ObjectMapper
import RealmSwift
import ObjectMapper_Realm

public class Items: Object, Mappable {

var images = List<ListImages>()
@objc dynamic var id = 0

required convenience public init?(map : Map){
   self.init()
}

public override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
   return "id"
}

public func mapping(map: Map) {
var images: [String]? = nil
images <- map["image"]

images?.forEach { image in
    let value = ListImages()
    value.value = image
    self.images.append(value)
  }
}
}


class ListImages:Object{
    @objc dynamic var value: String = ""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem using `RealmTypeCastTransform()`

In your code just add this

```
func mapping(map: Map) {
    imageURLs <- (map["image_urls"], RealmTypeCastTransform())
}
```

Now `import ObjectMapperAdditions` in the beginning of your file